# Не запускается внешняя обработка 1С через параметры запуска

Tags: 1с, обработка

Возникла необходимость запуска внешней обработки .epf при запуске 1С. Если эту обработку запустить из уже запущенной 1С, то открытие происходит без проблем. Если указывается как аргумент к ярлыку, то ничего не происходит после загрузки. Т.е. открывается интерфейс 1С и всё. Ни ошибок, ни предупреждений. Как можно разобраться и понять, в чем же может быть проблема?

Вот сам параметр запуска:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv82\common\1cestart.exe" /IBName "Информационная база" /N "Администратор"  /p "123456" /Execute "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\V8Exchan82.epf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было ссылаться к файлу 1cv8.exe, который находится в папке bin.

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативные варианты решения:

- Откройте 1с в режиме Конфигуратора, нажмите ПКМ на имя конфигурации в дереве метаданных(слева), выберите пункт "Открыть модуль управляемого приложения", найдите (в типовой) или создайте процедуру "ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы()" в которой пропишите запуск требуемой обработки
- Можно отредактировать файл:ibases.v8i 
  после строк

  [Имя_базы] 
  ... 
  External=0 
  ClientConnectionSpeed=Normal 
  App=Auto 
  WA=1 
  Version=8.2

добавить строку 
     AdditionalParameters=/Execute "путь_к_обработке"

- Можно прописать параметр в настройках запуска базы, в строке "Дополнительные параметры запуска":

  /Execute «C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\V8Exchan82.epf»